# How can I build c++ Qt5 application by CMake in MSYS2

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, msys2

I have a c++ qt5 "hello world" cmake project;
Here are my main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt files:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;
    widget.resize(640, 480);
    widget.setWindowTitle("Hello, world!!!");

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(&widget);

    QLabel * label = new QLabel("Hello, world!!!");
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter);
    gridLayout->addWidget(label);

    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(helloworld)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

message("cmake source dir = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

set (Qt5_DIR "/mingw64/lib/cmake/Qt5")

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(helloworld
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets)
```

I just copy CMakeList from [official page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) and write down some very basic main.cpp. 
Then I built it on my Linux (openSUSE 15.0) and everything works fine. 
Now I want to build in on MSYS2 (to get windows version). First I could not build cmake project because Qt5Config.cmake file was not found. I added

```
set (Qt5_DIR "/mingw64/lib/cmake/Qt5")
```

to find Qt5Config.cmake file "manually". 
After adding this to my cmake file the project had been built fine. 
But when I run `make` to compile program I get the following errors:

```
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target helloworld
[ 25%] Built target helloworld_autogen
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable helloworld.exe
CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1c): undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/build.make:102: helloworld.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

As I can understand there are some missing libraries that could not be found. 
But I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need CMakeLists.tx 
You may just push build button

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/PLLUG/CPPQT-MSYS2-Cmder You have to use 2 commands install-dev-env and install-qt5-env after that qtcreator & Git is incide

Comment: sorry, but I do not have any build button. I wonna use cmake to build my application both on linux and msys2 the same way. I use only vim to create my qt5 gui application. Is it wrong?

Comment: you have yo use qtcreator